# How do I get a list of available themes in Emacs 24?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I know that you can do

```
M-x load-theme RET
```

and get a list of available themes for auto-complete, of which you could select one.

What I'm looking for, is a way to get this list of themes through Emacs LISP, so that I can cycle through it with a custom key-binding, without having to look at all the available themes and switch to one manually.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `custom-available-themes` should give you the list of themes.

---

I did not know this “off the top of my head”, but Emacs is a fairly discoverable system once one is comfortable digging about in the Emacs Lisp code. Here is how I found this answer:

1. Started a non-customized instance of Emacs:

   ```
   % emacs -q
   ```

   I wanted to make sure none of my normal customizations (installed packages, et cetera) would interfere with my investigation.
2. Since the list is available during autocomplete after `M-x load-theme RET`, I started with that function:

   ```
   C-h f load-theme RET
   ```
3. Switched to the `*Help*` buffer and hit Enter on the link to the definition of `load-theme` in `custom.el`.
4. Scanned the definition of `load-theme` to see if it was arranging a custom completion handler. Its `(interactive …)` form uses the function `completing-read`, giving it the output of this form:

   ```
   (mapcar 'symbol-name (custom-available-themes))
   ```
5. A quick `C-h f RET` on `custom-availabe-themes` verified that this is the source of the list of available themes.

Comment: Cool! I'm not able to find a reference to the definition to `load-theme` in the *Help* buffer though

Comment: Hmm, it should probably show up as the word `custom.el` that is underlined (maybe a theme changed its appearance?). The full text in my instance reads: `load-theme is an interactive compiled Lisp function in \`custom.el'.`. The `custom.el` bit is underlined and takes me to the definition of `load-theme` when I move the point into it and hit `RET`.

Comment: That's strange, cause here in my buffer, the only text in the first statement is "load-theme is an interactive compiled Lisp function.", without any themes applied.

Comment: Ah, I also see that if my installation has neither a `custom.el.gz` or a `custom.el` file (i.e. if I temporarily rename it or move it aside). Is your installation of Emacs somehow stripped-down so that it only includes the compiled `.elc` files?

Comment: I acquired this Emacs 24 that I'm running right from apt. I guess this is the plain regular distribution of Emacs. So, not sure.

Comment: *apt*… It looks like the Emacs Lisp sources files are packaged separately on Debian-derived systems. You can probably install [`emacs24-el`](https://packages.debian.org/sid/emacs24-el) to get them.

Comment: I know it has been quite a long time now but I thought I should share what I created here: https://github.com/myTerminal/theme-looper

Comment: Thanks Chris for writing about the systematic approach you used to find the answer. This is very useful more than the answer itself :)